# Generar una imagen a partir de in video generado de un input file (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html5

quisiera saber si hay una manera de generar una imagen a partir de un video que fue puesto en un input type file este es mi código para poner la url en la etiqueta video que ya estaba renderizado

```
//html
<video controls><source src="" id="video_here"></video>
<inout type="file" id="file"/>
//script
$(document).on("change", "#file", function(evt) {
    var $source = $('#video_here');
    $source[0].src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
    $source.parent()[0].load();
});
```

y quiero saber si a partir de eso puedo generar una imagen o si de alguna otra forma puedo generar una imagen

Comment: Puedes consultar este enlace https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28834887/how-to-create-thumbnail-image-by-using-video-url-for-jquery-jplayer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EL procedimiento luego de cargar el video, es cargar una captura del video en un objeto canvas. Luego puedes colocar el resultado en una imagen usando la URL generada (usando `toDataURL()`)

```js
$(document).on("change", "#file", function(evt) {
    var video = $('#video_here')[0];
    video.onloadedmetadata=(function(){
      if (video.objectURL){
        URL.revokeObjectURL(video.src);
      }
      video.objectURL=false;
      var preview=document.createElement("canvas");
      console.log(video.videoWidth);
      preview.setAttribute("width",video.videoWidth);
      preview.setAttribute("height",video.videoHeight);
      var ctx=preview.getContext('2d');        
      setTimeout(function(){
        ctx.drawImage(video,0,0,video.videoWidth,video.videoHeight);

        // cargar en una imagen HTML
        var dataURL = preview.toDataURL();
        $("#preview-img").attr('src', dataURL);
      },100);

      
      
    });
    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
    video.play();
    video.currentPostion=1000;
    video.pause();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video controls id="video_here" width="320" ><source src="" ></video>
<input type="file" id="file" accept=".mp4" />
<hr>
Preview:
<img id="preview-img" alt="preview">
```